# Error thrown when react component refreshes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react typescript component that has the following componentDidMount method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ComponentFields.get(this.ComponentName)
        .then(activeFields => {
            this.setState({ activeFields });
        });
}
```

It has a state interface with following field

```
export interface ISettingsPageState {
    activeFields: Dictionary<IComponentField>,
}
```

where `IComponentField` is an interface.`ComponentFields.get(componentName: string)` is a static method which returns a `Promise<IDictionary<IComponentField>>`.

It works fine the first time it loads but when I refresh the page, the `setState` method in `componentDidMount` throws the following exception:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The code that was posted doesn't explain what can be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that this example doens't meet the mcve criteria was actually the hint I needed to figure out what was going wrong. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, a lot of cases solve themselves when you dissect them to provide MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was a child component throwing the error. Even though the exception was being thrown at the `setState` line, the problem was in my `render`method. If anyone has the same problem, I would suggest taking a look at the `render` method to see what's going wrong.